# If i need to incorporate swipe tab views with multiple activities what do i do?

Tags: android

I am following a tutorial on implementing tab swipe views in android studio and it has worked out fine. But then i had to use tab swipe use for multiple activities. For example, I have a main activity and in that main activity i have 3 buttons. With a click, each button open into another activity with 4 tabs in  it. 
Main actitity>Button 1> screen with tabs 1 2 3
main activity> button 2> screen with tabs 4 5 6
(These tabs 1 2 3 4 5 6 are infact activities)

The simpler version can be found here: 
http://easyway2in.blogspot.ae/2014/10/android-swipe-views-with-tabs.html

Now, what i did was:
I had  fragmentpageadapter file for main_activity already. I created fragmentpageadaptertwo for another activity with swipable tabs. Here is what my fragmentpageadapter.java and fragmentpageadaptertwo.java look like (BIG QUESTION:: DO I EVEN NEED TO DECLARE DIFFERENT FRAGMENTPAGEADPATER CLASSES?? ):

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            return new in_room_dining();
        case 1:
            return new laundry();
        case 2:
            return new house_keeping();
        case 3:
            return new miscellaneous();
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 4;
}
}
```

Here is what fragmentpagaadpatertwo.java looks like:

```
package com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax;

/**
 * Created by SHREYA BISHT on 11/28/2014.
 */
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
public class FragmentPageAdaptertwo extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public FragmentPageAdaptertwo (FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            return new gym();
        case 1:
            return new spa();
        case 2:
            return new recreational();
        case 3:
            return new events();
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 4;
}
}
```

What happens: When i run my application, it runs fine. main activity opens.I click on Button 1 which is supposed to take me to a screen with swipable tabs but at this point the application crashes.

Here is what i see in logcat:

```
11-27 15:17:39.929      885-885/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax, PID: 885
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax.amn_menu}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax.amn_menu.onCreate(amn_menu.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 15:17:43.339      885-885/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 885 SIG: 9
11-27 15:17:44.949    1103-1103/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 9% free 3606K/3940K, paused 103ms, total 105ms
11-27 15:17:45.689    1103-1103/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8d6de20, tid 1103
11-27 15:17:45.749    1103-1103/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-27 15:17:45.759    1103-1103/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

(amn_menu.java:23) is 
viewpager.setAdapter(ft1);

At this point I have way too many activites in my project, if my question is not clear, I can paste some more codes from my activities. Thanks

\\\\\\\edited\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

amn_menu.java

```
package com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax;


import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;


public class amn_menu extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
ActionBar actionbar;
ViewPager viewpager;
FragmentPageAdaptertwo ft1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_amn_menu);
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    ft1= new FragmentPageAdaptertwo (getSupportFragmentManager());
    actionbar = getActionBar();
    viewpager.setAdapter(ft1);
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Gym").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Spa").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Recreational").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Events").setTabListener(this));
    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException AT amn_menu.java:23, show  that file if posible

Comment: @oneway added amn_menu.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an error on identifiers.

```
19:   setContentView(R.layout.activity_amn_menu);
20:   viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  // <<-- here viewpager = null
21:   ft1= new FragmentPageAdaptertwo (getSupportFragmentManager());
22:   actionbar = getActionBar();
23:   viewpager.setAdapter(ft1);   // <--- NullPointerException HERE
24    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

So, **`R.id.pager`** do not exists in **`R.layout.activity_amn_menu`** Layour.

Look into `layout/activity_amn_menu.xml` for `R.id.pager` element, add it or fix the name in line 20.

Comment: before we look at the code, I wanted to ask if this is infact the correct way to do this. I need to have multiple fragmentpageadapter.java files right?

Comment: You may have up to one per FragmentActivity.

Comment: as oer the tutorial, I added <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager> to amn_menu.xml. that should do ?